# Using a table to keep the last used ID in a web server farm

Tags: mysql, database, thread-safety

I use a table with one row to keep the last used ID (I have my reasons to not use auto_increment), my app should work in a server farm so I wonder how I can update the last inserted ID (ie. increment it) and select the new ID in one step to avoid problems with thread safety (race condition between servers in the server farm).

Answer (score 2):

You're going to use a server farm for the database? That doesn't sound "right".

You may want to consider using GUID's for Id's. They may be big but they don't have duplicates.

With a single "next id" value you will run into locking contention for that record. What I've done in the past is use a table of ranges of id's (RangeId, RangeFrom, RangeTo). The range table has a primary key of "RangeId" that is a simple number (eg. 1 to 100). The "get next id" routine picks a random number from 1 to 100, gets the first range record with an id lower than the random number. This spreads the locks out across N records. You can use 10's, 100's or 1000's of range records. When a range is fully consumed just delete the range record.

If you're really using multiple databases then you can manually ensure each database's set of range records do not overlap.

Comment: oh, I actually meant a web server farm, sorry I should've mentioned that

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your ID column is only ever accessed in a lock - then only one person can read the highest and set the new highest ID.

You can do this in C# using a lock statement around your code that accesses the table, or in your database you can put together a transaction on your read/write.  I don't know the exact syntax for this on mysql.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually I can't use locking in C# because this is a server fram, I know that there's table locking in mysql but I was hoping for a solution with no locking as locking might cause troubles and affect performance.

Answer (score 1):

Use a transactional database and control transactions manually.  That way you can submit multiple queries without risking having something mixed up. Also, you may store the relevant query sets in stored procedures, so you can simply invoke these transactional queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems with performance, increment the ID by 100 and use a thread per "client" server. The thread should do the increment and hand each interested party a new ID. This way, the thread needs only access the DB once for 100 IDs.

If the thread crashes, you'll loose a couple of IDs but if that doesn't happen all the time, you shouldn't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the only way to get this out of a DB with nicely incrementing numbers is going to be transactional locks at the DB which is hideous performance wise. You can get a lockless behaviour using GUIDs but frankly you're going to run into transaction requirements in every CRUD operation you can think of anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your database is configured to run with a transaction isolation of READ_COMMITTED or better, then use one SQL statement that updates the row, setting it to the old value selected from the row plus an increment. With lower levels of transaction isolation you might need to use INSERT combined with SELECT FOR UPDATE.

As pointed out [by Aaron Digulla] it is better to allocate blocks of IDs, to reduce the number of queries and table locks.

The application must perform the ID acquisition in a separate transaction from any business logic, otherwise any transaction that needs an ID will end up waiting for every transaction that asks for an ID first to commit/rollback.

This article: http://www.ddj.com/architect/184415770 explains the HIGH-LOW strategy that allows your application to obtain IDs from multiple allocators. Multiple allocators improve concurrency, reliability and scalability.

There is also a long discussion here: [http://www.theserverside.com/patterns/thread.tss?thread_id=4228 "HIGH/LOW Singleton+Session Bean Universal Object ID Generator"](http://www.theserverside.com/patterns/thread.tss?thread_id=4228)

Comment: Edited answer because UPDATE table SET ID = ID + block_size works with READ_COMMITTED.